# Some parts in render mode white

Tags: shaders

when trying to animate some parts are white in render view, not sure what causes it.
[image]

Comment: Try removing any doubles or recalculate the mesh.
Also, switch to Cycles xd

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it, remove all materials then add them back